# Outputting rows from table in one single text field laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

Hi gladly I want to put the output of my rows from a table in on single text field. This is what I currently have in my view:

```
{{Form::label('tag', 'tags')}}
@foreach ($task->tagtask as $tt)                
<input type="text" name="tag_name" class="form-control" value='{{ $tt->tag['tag_name'] }}'>
@endforeach
```

The problem is if I have a task with for example 2 tags. Then its going to loop two times and then I have two textfields with each a value of a single tag. I would like to have one single textfield with all the tags that a task has as a value. But I really don't know how to achieve this.

Can someone help me, please? Gladly I'm waiting for your response. Anyway thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `@foreach` inside the `value` attribute:

```
{{Form::label('tag', 'tags')}}

<input type="text" name="tag_name" class="form-control" value='@foreach ($task->tagtask as $tt) {{ $tt->tag['tag_name'] }} @endforeach'>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer it works, but I still have a tiny question. I see two tags now, but between it I see two times a space. So the tags look like this: marketing  development    Between those tags there are two spaces. I have already checked my tags in the database, but there are nog spaces in there. Do you or someone else maybe know how  to solve this? If you do not know this, then I also don't really mind..

Comment: @superkytoz You may try remove space between `)` and `{{` and the same between `}}` and `@endforeach` or prepare data in PHP and pass to Blade only single value to put inside this input

Answer (score 1):

You can always use a little of pure PHP.

```
{{Form::label('tag', 'tags')}}
<input type="text" name="tag_name" class="form-control" value="<?php foreach($task->tagtask as $tt) echo $tt->tag['tag_name'];?>">
```